# Django - Order Queryset by method

Tags: python, django

I am trying to order this queryset by the number of posts associated with each board.

Here is the Board model:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    def num_posts(self):
        return self.post_set.all().count()
```

Here is the Post Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    content = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Board)
```

And here is the view where I am trying to get all of the boards, ordered by the number of posts on each one:

```
def index(request):
    board_list = Board.objects.order_by('num_posts')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'board_list':board_list
    })
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

And it isn't working. I get this error:

```
 Cannot resolve keyword 'num_posts' into field.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to order by method - this wouldn't translate to an SQL query well.

Here's what you can do:

```
from django.db.models import Count

board_list = Board.objects.annotate(num_posts=Count('post')).order_by('num_posts')
```

Comment: from django.db.models import Count

Comment: Thanks @remy_g! I always try to remember to include the imports, but in this case I forgot. I edited my post now.